# Android HTTP post and request data PHP

Tags: java, php, android, http

I'm really new to this type of programming, I switched from PHP to java apps.

I started this app which is used to scan QR codes and get information. It works very well. If I scan a QR code I get the information and I can Toast it on display.

However, I also need to send this string from the QR code as a POST to a php page where I do "the magic" and return the value back to my app.

I was googling a lot and I found this part of code:

```
 if (scanningResult != null) {
             String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();



// Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.domain.cz/app.php");

//This is the data to send
            String MyName = scanContent; //any data to send

            try {
// Add your data
                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("action", MyName));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

// Execute HTTP Post Request

                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                String response = httpclient.execute(httppost, responseHandler);

//This is the response from a php application
                    String reverseString = response;
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "response" + reverseString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "CPE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "IOE response " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }
```

Everything works perfectly, I can compile this app, run the QR code scanner and scan the code. But my app fails and crashes somewhere in this code.

Can you find my mistake? I can maybe attach the logcat log but I'm a bit confused by this Logging functionality. Here appears thousand of lines of code.

### Logcat

```
    03-20 06:42:10.945  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority [0], There is no sepolicy file.
03-20 06:42:10.975  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/SELinux﹕ Function: selinux_android_load_priority , spota verifySig and checkHash pass. priority version is VE=SEPF_GT-I9301I_4.4.2_0040
03-20 06:42:10.975  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/SELinux﹕ selinux_android_seapp_context_reload: seapp_contexts file is loaded from /data/security/spota/seapp_contexts
03-20 06:42:10.985  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
03-20 06:42:11.055  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ Sending WAIT chunk
03-20 06:42:11.055  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode W/ActivityThread﹕ Application com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode is waiting for the debugger on port 8100...
03-20 06:42:11.165  16134-16140/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/dalvikvm﹕ Debugger is active
03-20 06:42:11.255  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ Debugger has connected
03-20 06:42:11.255  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:11.455  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:11.655  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:11.855  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:12.055  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:12.255  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:12.465  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:12.665  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:12.865  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ waiting for debugger to settle...
03-20 06:42:13.065  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/System.out﹕ debugger has settled (1396)
03-20 06:42:13.175  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode E/MoreInfoHPW_ViewGroup﹕ Parent view is not a TextView
03-20 06:42:13.335  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ Get MotionRecognitionManager
03-20 06:42:13.415  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
03-20 06:42:13.415  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:13.435  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 0
03-20 06:42:13.435  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:13.515  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build:  ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.07
    Build Date: 01/27/14 Mon
    Local Branch: base_au149_adreno_au169_patches
    Remote Branch:
    Local Patches:
    Reconstruct Branch:
03-20 06:42:13.565  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
03-20 06:42:13.615  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:13.615  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
03-20 06:42:13.615  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:13.765  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:13.805  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:23.005  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:23.285  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode E/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
03-20 06:42:23.305  16134-16256/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode W/MediaPlayer﹕ info/warning (973, 0)
03-20 06:42:23.335  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/DecodeHintManager﹕ Hints from the Intent: {}
03-20 06:42:23.395  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
03-20 06:42:23.475  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/com.google.zxing.client.android.camera.open.OpenCameraInterface﹕ Opening camera #0
03-20 06:42:24.195  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Screen resolution: Point(1280, 720)
03-20 06:42:24.195  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Supported preview sizes: 1920x1080 1440x1080 1280x720 1056x864 960x720 800x480 720x480 640x480 352x288 320x240 176x144
03-20 06:42:24.195  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Found preview size exactly matching screen size: Point(1280, 720)
03-20 06:42:24.195  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Camera resolution: Point(1280, 720)
03-20 06:42:24.265  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Initial camera parameters: focallength-value-denominator=100;brightness-step=1;zoom=0;redeye-reduction-values=enable,disable;max-num-detected-faces-hw=2;scene-detect-values=off,on;qc-camera-features=30;face-detection-values=off,on;whitebalance=auto;max-sharpness=36;focallength-value-numerator=371;preview-format-values=yuv420sp,yuv420p;jpeg-thumbnail-quality=85;preview-format=yuv420sp;face-detection=off;auto-exposure-values=matrix,center,spot;iso=auto;fast-fps-mode=0;mce-values=enable,disable;flash-mode-values=off,auto,on,torch;preview-frame-rate=30;jpeg-thumbnail-width=512;video-size=1920x1080;scene-mode-values=auto,asd,landscape,snow,beach,sunset,night,portrait,backlight,sports,steadyphoto,flowers,candlelight,fireworks,party,night-portrait,theatre,action,AR;redeye-reduction=disable;preview-fps-range-values=(7500,119900);histogram=disable;face-recognition=off;camera-mode=0;preview-size-values=1920x1080,1440x1080,1280x720,1056x864,960x720,800x480,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;maxaperture-value-denominator=100;saturation-step=1;touch-af-aec=touch-off;smart-screen-exposure-values=vision-ae-normal,vision-ac-backlight;preview-fps-range=7500,119900;auto-whitebalance-lock=false;min-exposure-compensation=-12;llv_mode=0;antibanding=off;max-num-focus-areas=1;face-recognition-values=off,on;vertical-view-angle=42.5;video-stabilization-supported=false;sce-factor-step=10;maxaperture-value-numerator=253;qc-max-num-requested-faces=2;min-saturation=0;max-saturation=10;contrast-step=1;raw-size=3280x2464;max-brightness=6;supported-live-snapshot-sizes=3264x2448,3264x1836,3200x2400,2592x1944,2048x1536,2048x1152,1920x1080,1600x1200,1440x1080,1280x768,1280x720,1024x768,800x600,800x480,800x450,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;max-contrast=10;min-sce-factor=-100;picture-format-values=jpeg,bayer-qcom-10gbrg,bayer-qcom-10grbg,bayer-qcom-10rggb,bayer-qcom-10bggr,bayer-mipi-10gbrg,bayer-mipi-10grbg,bayer-mipi-10rggb,bayer-mipi-10bggr,yuv422sp,bayer-ideal-qcom-10grbg;video-hfr=off;supported-shot-modes=normal-shot,panorama-burst;exposure-compensation-step=0.166667;scene-detect=off;fnumber-value-numerator=240;picture-size=3264x2448;saturation=5;whitebalance-values=auto,incandescent,fluorescent,warm-fluorescent,daylight,cloudy-daylight,twilight,shade;picture-format=jpeg;zsl=off;lensshade-values=enable,disable;selectable-zone-af=auto;video-hfr-values=90;iso-values=auto,ISO_HJR,100,200,400,800,1600;selectable-zone-af-values=;lensshade=enable;preferred-preview-size-for-video=1920x1080;anti-shake=0;min-sharpness=0;intelligent-mode=0;mce=enable;hfr-size-values=800x450;snapshot-picture-flip=off;zoom-supported=true;metering=center;denoise-values=denoise-off,denoise-on;zsl-values=off,on;sharpness=36;contrast=5;scene-mode=auto;jpeg-quality=85;histogram-values=enable,disable;metering-areas=(0,0,0,0,0);min-contrast=0;video-size-values=1920x1080,1440x1080,1280x720,800x450,720x480,640x480,352x288,320x240,176x144;skinToneEnhancement=0;preview-size=1920x1080;focal-length=3.71;ae-bracket-hdr-values=Off,AE-Bracket;denoise=denoise-on;video-flip=off;max-sce-factor=100;preview-frame-rate-values=15,30;max-num-metering-areas=10;preview-flip=off;focus-mode-values=auto,infinity,macro,continuous-video,continuous-picture;vtmode=0;jpeg-thumbnail-size-values=512x288,480x288,256x154,432x288,512x384,352x288,320x240,176x144,160x160,0x0;zoom-ratios=100,104,109,114,119,125,129,134,139,144,150,154,159,164,169,175,179,184,189,194,200,204,209,214,219,225,229,234,239,244,250,254,259,264,269,275,279,284,289,294,300,304,309,314,319,325,329,334,339,344,350,354,359,364,369,375,379,384,389,394,400,404,409,414;dis-values=enable,disable;dual_mode=0;picture-size-values=3264x2448,3264x1836,2560x1920,2560x1440,2048x1536,2048x1152,1920x1080,1600x1200,1280x960,1280x720,640x480;touch-af-aec-values=touch-off,touch-on;smart-screen-exposure=0;luma-adaptation=3;min-brightness=0;horizontal-view-angle=54.8;firmware-mode=none;flip-mode-values=off,flip-v,flip-h,flip-vh;skinToneEnhancement-values=enable,disable;jpeg-thumbnail-height=288;smooth-zoom-supp
03-20 06:42:24.265  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Requesting flash mode value from among: [off]
03-20 06:42:24.265  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Supported flash mode values: [off, auto, on, torch]
03-20 06:42:24.265  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Can set flash mode to: off
03-20 06:42:24.265  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Flash mode already set to off
03-20 06:42:24.275  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Requesting focus mode value from among: [auto]
03-20 06:42:24.275  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Supported focus mode values: [auto, infinity, macro, continuous-video, continuous-picture]
03-20 06:42:24.275  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Can set focus mode to: auto
03-20 06:42:24.275  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/CameraConfiguration﹕ Focus mode already set to auto
03-20 06:42:24.315  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/DecodeThread﹕ Hints: {POSSIBLE_FORMATS=[QR_CODE], NEED_RESULT_POINT_CALLBACK=com.google.zxing.client.android.ViewfinderResultPointCallback@423bcf78}
03-20 06:42:24.765  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/AutoFocusManager﹕ Current focus mode 'auto'; use auto focus? true
03-20 06:42:24.785  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/MediaPlayer﹕ Don't send intent. msg.arg1 = 0, msg.arg2 = 0
03-20 06:42:24.785  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
03-20 06:42:24.785  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode I/Choreographer﹕ Skipped 80 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
03-20 06:42:24.805  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/CameraManager﹕ Calculated framing rect: Rect(240, 135 - 1040, 585)
03-20 06:42:25.355  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ onVisibilityChanged() is called, visibility : 4
03-20 06:42:25.355  16134-16134/com.example.sunny.kpcombarcode D/AbsListView﹕ unregisterIRListener() is called
```

### SOLVED:

adding

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }
```

in main activity under setContent .. I think the problem was in Too much work in this thread. But this small snippet solve it

Comment: Attach the logcat please. It tells all.

Comment: You cannot have a Toast in an AsyncTask or thread. Now where do you put that code? NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: You solved it. Yes. But in the wrong way. You posted the wrong log which has nothing to do with the NetworkOnMainThreadException you had. If you want normal code than use an AsyncTask or thread to put the network code in.